# Are there any Microsoft Word 2010 table styles ? The nice looking ones instead of current ones

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Such as table styles that are using nice gradients or effects. Are there any styles that i can download and use ? Microsoft office 2010 or 2007 Word tables.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm not sure of any sites that allow you to download pre-made styles. However they are very easy to make your own, you would probably have more luck creating your own so you can customize to your liking. Check out this Youtube video for a demonstration of how to createa a table style: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8QoRoDa1fY.